# drupal 6 node server.js populate error on running?

Tags: nodes

I have followed [drupal.org instruction](https://www.drupal.org/node/1713530) to install node.js and NPM, and when I install all packages I get this error:

```
while running node server.js

  server = express.createServer();
                   ^
TypeError: Object function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
  mixin(app, proto, false);

  app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
  app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
  app.init();
  return app;
} has no method 'createServer'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/nodejs/server.js:943:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
```